# The Angular application I serve with NGINX does not display images

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose, frontend

I'm writing a full stack application. I wrote Angular for the front end and serve it with nginx docker. I can receive data by communicating with the backend. Imagepath is among this data. In this way, I can show the images locally, but I think it is due to Docker and Nginx that the image path is not displayed even if it is correct. I leave an image as an example, the image src part is correct. If I go to this path in the container, I can see the picture, but I cannot see the picture on the screen.
[Didn't show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmqeR.png)

My nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/browser;
        index index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level 9;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /users_books_pictures/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/data/;
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile for frontend:

```
FROM node:20.10-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npx ngcc --properties es2023 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:stable
COPY --from=build /app/dist/librari-fy/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    container_name: postgredatabase
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: Library
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app_internal_network
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 80s 
    
  backend:
    image: sahinyakici/librarybackend:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: backend
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - app_internal_network
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/app/users_books_pictures

  frontend:
    container_name: librarify
    image: sahinyakici/librarify:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app_internal_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/usr/share/nginx/html/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  app_internal_network:
    driver: bridge
```

I changed the Nginx configurations and searched for an answer in the forum but could not find it.

[Incoming data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZt3x.png)

Comment: Hey (again) :) Can you share the image URL your browser tries to fetch ? You should be able to see it in the Network section of your browser's console, with the failing requests.

Comment: Hello again, you can't imagine how happy I am to see you :) I will store my images in the frontend folder where NGINX is located. Therefore, when I receive data, I bring it in the form of a path. So it's like this:
"imagePath": "/usr/share/nginx/html/browser/assets/images/default.jpg"

Comment: I also added an image to the post to show the incoming data

Comment: The `root` URL of your NGINX server is already set to `/usr/share/nginx/html/browser`, so you don't need to add this prefix to your `imagePath` data. NGINX will look in the `root` folder by default and try to get a file at the path specified by your URL, from the `root` folder. If you try to open `http://localhost/assets/images/default.jpg` in your browser does it work ?

Comment: Yes, i tried and it's work.

Comment: Ok so that was the issue :) You need to remove the `/usr/share/nginx/html/browser` prefix of your `imagePath` datas and it should do the trick :) I will post the answer as final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` URL of your NGINX server is already set to `/usr/share/nginx/html/browser`, so you don't need to add this prefix to your `imagePath` data. NGINX will look in the root folder by default and try to get a ressource at the path specified by your URL, from the root folder.

Therefore you need to remove `/usr/share/nginx/html/browser` prefix of your `imagePath` datas and it should do the trick :)

Comment: You saved me for the second time. Thank you very much again :)

Comment: Always a pleasure :D